# Execution plan for COMPUTE BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, execution-plan, database-internals

I understand that the [`COMPUTE BY` feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708(v=sql.105).aspx) is deprecated. Out of curiosity I would like to know how the query processor executes a `COMPUTE BY` query. The execution plan does not contain any hint:

[image]

How does the query processor execute `COMPUTE BY` and how can I obtain an accurate execution plan?

Here is some T-SQL to play with:

```
 create table employee(
    ID          int,
    name        nvarchar (10),
    salary      int,
    start_date  datetime,
    city        nvarchar (10),
    region      char (1))
GO
insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (1,  'Jason', 40420,  '02/01/94', 'New York', 'W')

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (2,  'Robert',14420,  '01/02/95', 'Vancouver','N')
GO

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (3,  'Celia', 24020,  '12/03/96', 'Toronto',  'W')

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (4,  'Linda', 40620,  '11/04/97', 'New York', 'N')
GO

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (5,  'David', 80026,  '10/05/98', 'Vancouver','W')
GO

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (6,  'James', 70060,  '09/06/99', 'Toronto',  'N')
GO

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (7,  'Alison',90620,  '08/07/00', 'New York', 'W')
GO

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (8,  'Chris', 26020,  '07/08/01', 'Vancouver','N')
GO

insert into employee (ID, name,    salary, start_date, city,       region)
              values (9,  'Mary',  60020,  '06/09/02', 'Toronto',  'W')
GO

select * from employee
GO
/*
ID          name       salary      start_date              city       region
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------------------- ---------- ------
          1 Jason            40420 1994-02-01 00:00:00.000 New York   W
          2 Robert           14420 1995-01-02 00:00:00.000 Vancouver  N
          3 Celia            24020 1996-12-03 00:00:00.000 Toronto    W
          4 Linda            40620 1997-11-04 00:00:00.000 New York   N
          5 David            80026 1998-10-05 00:00:00.000 Vancouver  W
          6 James            70060 1999-09-06 00:00:00.000 Toronto    N
          7 Alison           90620 2000-08-07 00:00:00.000 New York   W
          8 Chris            26020 2001-07-08 00:00:00.000 Vancouver  N
          9 Mary             60020 2002-06-09 00:00:00.000 Toronto    W
*/


-- COMPUTE BY
SELECT salary, Name
FROM Employee
ORDER BY ID, Name
COMPUTE SUM(Salary)
GO

/*
salary      Name
----------- ----------
      40420 Jason
      14420 Robert
      24020 Celia
      40620 Linda
      80026 David
      70060 James
      90620 Alison
      26020 Chris
      60020 Mary
sum
===========
     446226
*/

GO

drop table employee
```

([Source](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Analytical-Functions/COMPUTESUMSalary.htm))

The results from this single `SELECT` are:

[image]

Comment: It seems to me like a proprietary replacement for analytical clause in ; the same result will be with `SUM(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY id) ` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How does the query processor execute COMPUTE BY?*

It is a hard-coded sequence of operations at the top of the execution tree. There is a simple stream accumulation (hence the ordering requirement), some logic to detect the start of a new group, a little computation and data value copying, and direct calls to construct the alternate TDS result sets per group. Some example call stacks from a query using `COMPUTE BY` are shown below:

[image: Accumulation]

[image: Copying]

[image: Alternate TDS result set generation]

> *and how can I obtain an accurate execution plan?*

You can't, because `COMPUTE BY` is not implemented in the same way as other plan operations. The replacement `ROLLUP` support does use the regular execution framework, automatically providing showplan information. An additional benefit of `ROLLUP` is that it does not use alternate TDS result sets, providing better client compatibility. In short, no one will miss `COMPUTE`.